# The necessity of ACK in INVITE SIP transactions

Tags: sip, voip

I am just curious, what is the fundamental reason to have 200 OK responses from a remote end point to be ACKed by the local end point?  RFC 3261 states that it is needed for stability purposes but does not go into details. The only reason that comes to my head is the case with call forking. So, if an AOR is registered at multiple end points and these end points respond simultaneously with a 200 OK message, then an ACK will actually indicate which of the remote parties will participate in a peer-to-peer connection. Is there any other reason to end and INVITE hand shake with an ACK?

Answer (score 1):

It's because SIP needs some responses (only INVITE responses in practise) to be reliably transmitted in situations where the underlying transport is unreliable, such as with UDP.

The ACK request is the way for the (UAC User Agent Client) to let the UAS (User Agent Server) know that it received the final response to an INVITE request. Without employing something like the ACK request there would always be the risk that the UAS response would not get through to the UAC and the call would be left sitting in an incorrect state.

The ACK request doesn't have any specific role in call forking. In the case you've described in a call with multiple end points BYE requests will be sent to any call legs that are not required. ACK requests still need to be sent to any UAS that responds irrespective of whether the UAC wants that call leg to proceed or not.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. So, in the case of TCP, there is no use for ACK?

Comment: There are cases when ACKs are still necessary even when a TCP transport is in use. For example if an upstream stateless proxy uses TCP for one UA but UDP for a different UA. As such a SIP implementation is required to support ACKs on both UDP and TCP transports.